# Git SSH Protocol Remember Password

Tags: git, ssh, debian, vps

I've a git repository on a Debian VPS, everything is working okay. Except that I don't want to keep entering my root password everytime I pull or push. Is there a way to remember passwords?

I know about SSH, I managed to set it up correctly on GitHub, but I couldn't do it for my Debian VPS.

I know how to use ssh-keygen, but what to do on the server?

Comment: um? Put your public key on the server?

Comment: You shouldn't be entering the `root` password at all for accessing a git repository.

Comment: How do I put the public key on the server? And how do I make Git Bash use that key? I've already generated the key and it's working on GitHub just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Regular process is that you put your public key on to the authorized_keys file on ~/.ssh for the user you're connecting with.

If you have some product-specific stuff (git could be installed with gitosis, gitolite, gitorious), provide more details as to how you've done it.

Comment: I've done that. When I connect to root@host.com:path/to/repo it still asks me for a password, I'm using Git Bash. Git is installed alone, and the repo is initialized using: "git init --bare".

Comment: Ok. And you have correct permissions set for the authorized_keys?

Comment: I haven't used any products, like I said I used git alone. The git repo is there, I could push and pull normally. What I'm seeking is a way to remember the password.

Comment: adding an ssh key means that no password would be used, but the ssh key. Apparently for you it's not recognized. What kind of format do you use for git clone/pull? Which kind of an url?

Comment: authorized_keys and .ssh need to have 700 permissions, so only for the user himself.

Comment: The url I use is root@host.com/path/to/repo. Permissions are set. Still asks me for the password

Comment: you do notice that you've now given two different urls, `root@host.com/path/to/repo` and `root@host.com:path/to/repo`. Both can not be true. I would recommend adding the exact steps you've done, including proper url format and ssh debugging turned on, into the question, as well as the information which files you did place and where.